# Converting from unsigned long int to signed int and vice versa

Tags: c, int, long-integer, unsigned, signed

I would like to pass a signed int to `gsl_rng_uniform_int (const gsl_rng * r, unsigned long int n)`. The signed int that I'm passing is greater than or equal to zero. The function will return a number between `0` and `n`, so if I pass it a positive signed int, it will return something that is in the range of a signed int. I then want to store the return value in a signed int. What's the cleanest way to do this with the obvious expected behaviour? I'm on a 64-bit compiler on a 64-bit Linux machine.

**Update**
Sorry, folks. Please ignore. The problem with my code was actually elsewhere. I misinterpreted the output of `gdb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with:

```
int input = something;
int result = gsl_rng_uniform_int(r, input);
```

Likely the compiler will warn about an unsafe narrowing conversion, so change to:

```
// 0 <= return value < input, so conversion is safe
int result = (int) gsl_rng_uniform_int(r, input);
```

Or for safety:

```
if (input <= 0) { panic(); }
unsigned long rawresult = gsl_rng_uniform_int(r, input);
if (rawresult > INT_MAX) { panic(); }
int result = (int) rawresult;
```

Those lines could be wrapped in a helper function:

```
int gsl_rng_uniform_signed(const gsl_rng *r, int input) {
    if (input <= 0) { panic(); }
    unsigned long rawresult = gsl_rng_uniform_int(r, input);
    if (rawresult > INT_MAX) { panic(); }
    return (int) rawresult;
}
```

In any case testing your input is typically more useful than testing the output of functions you rely on, and if you trust `gsl_rng_uniform_int` then testing the input is sufficient.

[Edit: wow, Google indexes SO really aggressively. I just searched to check that `gsl_rng_uniform_signed` isn't already a function, and found myself.]

Answer (score 1):

If the function expects an `unsigned long` you can pass with no problem an `unsigned long`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned short` and `unsigned char`, the standard guarantees that.

If you pass a `signed` but negative `int`, you will not obtain the correct results, since it will be evaluated to a very big int by the function.

The best way is to check if it the signed int is `>= 0` before passing it.

I hope I understood your question correctly.